# Calling variable superclass method

Tags: python, super, superclass

I'm trying to call a method of the superclass by using a variable method name. Normally, I would see the following two lines of code as equivalent:

```
someObj.method()
someObj.__getattribute__( 'method' )()
```

And in fact I believe, this is also what actually happens when I use the first line. However, in the following example, the second line produces a weird problem.

I use [`super`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#super) to construct a super object and call the method of the super class. Doing it directly works as expected, but using `__getattribute__` to get the method first, results in a indefinite loop which calls the method of the subclass again and again.

See the following code:

```
class A:
    def example ( self ):
        print( 'example in A' )

class B ( A ):
    def example ( self ):
        print( super( B, self ).example )
        print( super( B, self ).__getattribute__( 'example' ) )
        super( B, self ).example()
        #super( B, self ).__getattribute__( 'example' )()

        print( 'example in B' )

x = B()
x.example()
```

If you run that code, everything works as expected, and you should get an output similar to this:

```
<bound method B.example of <__main__.B object at 0x01CF6C90>>
<bound method B.example of <__main__.B object at 0x01CF6C90>>
example in A
example in B
```

So both methods, the one with the direct access and the one via `__getattribute__`, look identical. If you however replace the method call by the commented-out line, you'll end up with a recursion runtime error.

Why does this happen, and more importantly, how can I actually access the method in the same way as python internally does, when I use the working line?

#### edit

When I thought I already tried everything, I found this to be working:

```
super.__getattribute__( super( B, self ), 'example' )()
```

It actually equals to `super( B, self ).example`.

Comment: aren't you supposed to be using `getattr(obj, 'attrname')` rather than `obj.__getattr__('attrname')` ?

Comment: Oh, you are right! For some reason I though `obj.x` would be equivalent to `obj.__getattribute__( 'x' )` when it was actually equivalent to `getattr( obj, 'x' )`. Still, what kind of magic does `getattr` do then? – Also you might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371753/python-using-getattribute-method, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810526/python-calling-a-method-of-an-instances-member-by-name-using-getattribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't** use `__getattribute__` for this: it does not do what you think it does. (It is a specialized part of Python's machinery, mainly for use if you're implementing new attribute access magic.)

For normal attribute access, use the `getattr` / `setattr` / `delattr` builtins:

```
self.example           == getattr(self, 'example')
super(B, self).example == getattr(super(B, self), 'example')
```

(If you want to understand what `__getattribute__` does, read the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html) and Python [Data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) reference.)

Answer (score 0):

Getting the `example` attribute of a `B` object results in a bound copy of `B.example`. Calling this will result in a recursion error. That you call `A.__getattribute__()` is irrelevant; you still have a `B` object.