# funcCalling arbitrary class functions for all members of a list of instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, design-patterns

I am trying to create a wrap for a class `_class1_` (probably, another class) that will have inside a list of several instances of `_class1_`, some additional variables, some functions that will operate with this list and also wraps for (nearly) all the functions of `_class1_`, that should actually just call the corresponding functions for all the `_class1_` objects stored in the list with the same set of parameters.

Could anyone suggest a better way to do that then just to implement all this functions (that will iterate through a list and call the corresponding functions from `List_class1`) by hand?

Example

```
class class2:
    def __init__(self, N):
         self._N = N
         self.List_class1 = []
         for i in range(0, self._N): 
             self.List_class1.append(class1())

    def function1(self, params)
        for i in range(0, self._N):
               List_class1[i].function1(params)

    def function2(self, params)
        ret = []
        for i in range(0, self._N):
               ret.append(List_class1[i].function2(params))
        return ret
```

So if a have a number of functions in class1 that I wand to adapt like that, maybe someone can suggest a way to do that wo just rewriting?

Comment: How will these functions be defined? Are you looking for a decorator implementation?

Comment: The code was corrected following the suggestions of @abarnert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there are a lot of things about this code that are incorrect, or at least weird:

- You have a shared class attribute `__N` holding an empty list—but in `__init__`, you immediately hide that with an instance variable of the same name, presumably holding a number. So, that class attribute is never going to do anything.
- There's also no reason for it to be called `__N`. The only reason for double underscores is when you need to protect against superclasses or subclasses accidentally using the same name for something incompatible.
- You're using another shared class attribute `List_class1`, but you're initializing it in your `__init__`. This makes sense for cases like, e.g., registering all instances of a class with the class, but it doesn't make sense for cases where you're trying to create a list per instance. When you construct a dozen `class2(10)`s, you want each one to have 10 `class1` instances, not all of them to share the same 120, right?
- Your `function1` and `function2` aren't methods, and can't be called, because they take no `self`. Or, rather, they *do* take a `self`, but under the unusual name `params`. Which means they end up passing `self` as the params to every function in `class1`.

Anyway, it looks like what you're trying to do is create a sort of generic proxy, but one that does a "fan-out" proxy to a list of objects, instead of just proxying to a single object.

So, the same basic techniques for generic proxies will work.

---

For example, you can do it dynamically with `__getattr__`:

```
class class2:
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.c1s = [class1() for _ in range(N)]

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name.startswith('_'):
            raise AttributeError(name)
        methods = []
        for c1 in self.c1s:
            attr = getattr(c1, name)
            if callable(attr):
                methods.append(attr)
        if methods:
            def _map(*args, **kw):
                return [method(*args, **kw) for method in methods]
            return _map
        raise AttributeError(name)

class class1:
    def function1(self, x, y):
        return x+y
    def function2(self):
        return 'function 2!'

c2 = class2(3)
print(c2.function1(2, 3))
print(c2.function2())
```

This will print `[5, 5, 5]` and then `["function 2!", "function 2!", "function 2!"]`.

---

Or, since you only want to hold `class1` instances, you can do it statically. This has the advantage that `class2.function2` will be a real method that you can see in the `__dict__`, so your interactive interpreter can autocomplete it, etc.

```
class class2:
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.c1s = [class1() for _ in range(N)]

for name, value in inspect.getmembers(class1, callable):
    if name.startswith('_'):
        continue
    setattr(class2, name, lambda self, *args, _v=value, **kw: [_v(c1, *args, **kw) for c1 in self.c1s])
```

OK, that last one could probably be a bit prettier instead of a horrible one-liner, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

One way that could work for you is to override the `__getattr__` method for your wrapper class. This gets called when an instance attribute can't be found (ie. any functions not implemented in your wrapper that are in your main class).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810526/python-calling-a-method-of-an-instances-member-by-name-using-getattribute) for something similar, but only with a single class rather than a list of them.

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def func_1(self):
        print(f"func_1: {self.name}")

    def func_2(self):
        print(f"func_2: {self.name}")


class AttributeGroup:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attributes = []

    def add_attribute(self, function):
        self.attributes.append(function)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for attr in self.attributes:
            attr(*args, **kwargs)


class AllThings:
    things = []

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        attrs = AttributeGroup()
        for thing in self.things:
            attrs.add_attribute(thing.__getattribute__(key))
        return attrs


group = AllThings()
group.things.append(Thing('a'))
group.things.append(Thing('b'))

group.func_1()
group.func_2()
```

The `__getattr__` method in the `AllThings` class should return a single attribute, hence the `FunctionGroup` class that just passes the call to all of the functions that it has collected.

The above code should print:

```
func_1: a
func_1: b
func_2: a
func_2: b
```

You could also then make the attribute group class iterable in some way so that you could get all attributes in a list, rather than just being able to call all the functions

```
# AttributeGroup class
def __getitem__(self, item):
    return self.attributes[item]

# main
for each in group.name:
    print(each)
```

Prints:

```
a
b
```